# Django - saving two records at the same time with a foreign key relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to be able to save two records in two database tables at the same time with one of the tables having foreign key relation to the other table.

models.py

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    Modlel1Filed1 = models.CharField()

class Model2 (models.Model):
    Model2Filed1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    Modle2Field2 = models.CharField()
```

Below is how I save the data using Model1:

```
p = Model1.objects.create(Model1Filed1=some_data_here)
p.save()
```

For Model2 I tried:

```
p = Model1.objects.get(pk=p.pk)
f = Model2.objects.create(Model2Filed1=p.id, Modle2Field2=some_data)
f = save()
```

but I'm getting an error like this:

```
Cannot assign "78": "Model2.Model2Filed1" must be a "Model1" instance.
```

Any ides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: `"Model2.Model2Filed1" must be a "Model1" instance`:

```
f = Model2.objects.create(Model2Filed1=p, Modle2Field2=some_data)
```

changed `Model2Filed1=p.id` to `Model2Filed1=p`

Comment: +1 - also i dont think you need Model1.objects.get(pk=p.pk), as you have just created it, p will already = the model instance.

Comment: @JamesO I just realized that so I took that line off. Thank you!